# Symfony form not populating join table in Doctrine many-to-many association

Tags: xml, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have two doctrine entities <kbd>Product</kbd> and <kbd>Order</kbd> which I have set up with a `many-to-many` association in XML.

My `/newProduct` route and form works and I can `flush()` the entity to its table in the database - however I think this is only working because there is no associated <kbd>Order</kbd> defined in this form.

Conversely, my `/neworder` route (below) generates the form ok but when I submit it I get:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 605 and defined

I have tried commenting out the `__construct()` in Order as well as Product but I still get the same error message. I am wondering if it could be from the `addProduct(\AppBundle\ProductOrder $product)` method (see order.php below) however this was auto-generated by Doctrine. I have tried regenerating entities and updating the doctrine schema in the hope that something will fix it but so far I've had no luck.

**My Controller:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\Order;

class DefaultController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/neworder", name="new_order")
     */
    public function newOrderAction(Request $request)
    {
        $order = new Order();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form = $this->CreateFormBuilder($order)
            ->add('products', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Product',
                'choice_label' => 'Description',
            ))
            ->add('Quantity', 'integer')
            ->add('Units', 'text')
            ->add('Save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Order'))
            ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($order);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:new.order.form.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
}
```

**My Order.php entity:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Order
{
    public $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Add Product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\ProductOrder $product
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function addProduct(\AppBundle\ProductOrder $product)
    {
        $product->addOrder($order);
       #$this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Products.orm.xml:**

```
<entity name="Product" table="product"
        repository-class="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository">

    <many-to-many target-entity="Order" inversed-by="Product" field="orders">
        <join-table name="products_orders">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="Product_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="Orders_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
</entity>
```

**Orders.orm.xml:**

```
<entity name="Order" table="order"
        repository-class="AppBundle\Entity\OrderRepository">

   <many-to-many field="products" mapped-by="orders" target-entity="Product" />
</entity>
```

Comment: Read and understand form collections. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html. Your current code is trying to use a single entry field as an array.  And that is just not going to end well.

Comment: I believe your relationships are bad designed. Take a look of this: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/ecommerce/develop/doc/reference/architecture/index.html

Comment: Hint: You will need to make a ProjectOrder entity with Quantity and Units properties and many to one relations with Product and Order..

Comment: Thanks once again @Cerad :) I haven't see the for_collections link so will have a thorough read through. However regarding the `ProjectOrder` entity you mentioned - isn't this the `products_orders` join table created in my `Products.orm.xml` though?

Comment: Yep but I'm assuming that you want to add quantity and units to it?  An order can contains multiple products each with it's own quantity?  Doctrine does not support additional attributes on the auto-generated join table.  To get additional attributes you need to make an actual entity.